# C++ OStream Inheritance and Manipulators

Tags: c++, iostream

I have a class that inherits from `ostream` but the manipulators fail to compile. For instance:

```
QLogger &logger = QLogger::getInstance();

logger << hex << 10 << endl;
```

Complains about `logger << hex`. If I cast logger to an `ostream` it will work but that is pretty ham-handed.

How can I extend my class so that it behaves as an `ostream` with manipulators?

Thanks,

Kenny

```
class LIBEXPORT QLogger: public std::ostream
{
    friend class boost::thread_specific_ptr< QLogger >;

    friend class QLoggerFunnel;

public:

    // Priority for message filtering.
    //
    // DEBUG   Detailed information that may be useful during development or troubleshooting.
    // NORMAL  Message will be useful during normal operation.
    // WARNING Message indicates an unhealthy condition but the system should continue to operate.
    // FAULT   Message indicates a critical error. The system may not operate normally.
    enum Priority
    {
        DEBUG, NORMAL, WARNING, FAULT
    };

    // DEPRECATED: Defined for backward compatibility.
    static const Priority LOW = NORMAL;

    static const Priority HIGH = WARNING;

    static const Priority URGENT = FAULT;

    // Returns a reference to the global instance.
    static QLogger& getInstance();

    // DEPRECATED: Use instead: QLogger::instance() << "Example message." << std::endl
    static AWI_DEPRECATED QLogger& stream( QLogger::Priority priority = NORMAL );

    QLogger &operator<<( Priority p );

    // Messages with a priority below the threshold are discarded.
    void setThreshold( Priority priority );

    Priority getThreshold( void ) const;

    // Set the priority of messages.
    void setPriority( Priority priority );

    Priority getPriority( void ) const;

protected:

    static void handleThreadExit( QLogger *logger );

    QLogger();

    QLogger( const QLogger& );

    virtual ~QLogger();

    QLogger& operator=( const QLogger& );

    void write( std::ostream &destination );

    void synchronize( void );

    // Prepends information to each line of its associated output stream.
    class StampBuffer: public std::stringbuf
    {
        public:

            StampBuffer();

            virtual ~StampBuffer();

            // String to be displayed before each line.
            void setPreamble( const char *p );

            virtual int sync();

            void write( std::ostream &destination );

        protected:

            boost::mutex _mutex;

            std::stringstream _stream1;

            std::stringstream _stream2;

            // Active stream being written to.
            std::stringstream *_write;

            std::stringstream *_read;

            const char *_preamble;
    };

    class NullBuffer: public std::stringbuf
    {
        public:

            NullBuffer();

            virtual ~NullBuffer();

            virtual int overflow( int c )
            {
                return (c);
            }
    };

    StampBuffer _buffer;

    NullBuffer _null_buffer;

    Priority _threshold;

    Priority _priority;
};
```

Comment: It would probably help to see the declaration for `Logger`.

Comment: Sorry. I should have formatted that code.

Comment: I added the declaration. It includes my experiment to use Nawaz's suggestion.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but you added the declaration of class `QLogger`, but used class `Logger` in your example...

Comment: That's confusing. In the original post I just typed out an example. I'll correct it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you implement a member function, then inherited overloads of that same function aren't considered in overload resolution. If you change your custom `operator<<` overloads to be friend global functions rather than members, this should work fine. The cast forces the compile to choose `operator<<()` from those defined in `ostream`.

The special overload for the function pointer isn't needed.

Comment: Do you have and idea why I have to do any of this? If my class is an ostream why doesn't it behave as one? I'll try your suggestion but I'm wondering what else my class won't do.

Comment: Overloads declared in the derived type hide the names from the base class. You should also be able to work around with `using std::ostream::operator<<`: http://ideone.com/6ImOp

Comment: Wait. Are you saying that because I defined operator<<(Priority p) that the other operator<< are not considered? Ouch! Sorry, I was thinking that the comment was directed to the second overload that I added based on a suggestion that has since been deleted.

Comment: Yeah, don't define any `operator<<()` members; move them all to be global functions.